# Activate cross column drag and drop using angular material without Prevent shifting/movement of the items in a cdkDropList

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

**Requirement** - Activate cross column drag and drop using angular material without Prevent shifting/movement of the items in a cdkDropList.

**Conditions** -  cdkDropList are created dynamically

**Tried** -

*Css translation* -

```css
.cdk-drop-list-receiving {
    .drag-box {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    }
}
```

*Directive* - cdkDropListSortingDisabled

Dynamically adding inline css for  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) while dragging
Result - Applied inline css is replaced by material inbuilt code of transform.

Example - (cdkDragMoved)="onDragMoved($event)"

```js
cdkDragMove($event) {
    const allDraggingElements: any = document.querySelectorAll('.cdk-drop-list-receiving .cdk-drag');
    [...allDraggingElements].map(ele => ele.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)!important');
  }
```

*Implemented* --- $event.source._dragRef.reset() on cdkDragEnded

*Problem video* https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2GLmULUZwVtR4kzjUtwCs74Qjiq4HgG/view?usp=sharing

In the above video when we drag and drop in same column it is working perfectly . But when we are trying cross column drag and drop I want to prevent card from shifting.

**Code implemented for same column drag and drop** -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution1: You can add a CSS rule to the .cdk-drag-placeholder class like this

```
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
display:none;
}
```

Note: This will affect the list you are draggin it from too, so you might want to get more specific to the container you are dropping it into

Solution 2-

Try putting this on the source list item

```
<div *cdkDragPlaceholder style="height: 0px"></div>
```

Comment: Also try adding important in the first solution above